# Showing equality of fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I've come across some trouble in a proof and feel like I need a little push to reach the contradiction I'm aiming for!

My goal is to show equality of the fields in the tower $K\subseteq K(a^{1/p})\subseteq K(a^{1/p^2})$, where $p$ is a prime not equal to the characteristic of $K$ and $K(a^{1/p})=K(a^{1/p^2})$ by assumption. Additionally, we have established that $K(a^{1/p})$ is the splitting field of $x^p-a$ and $K(a^{1/p^2})$ the splitting field for $x^{p^2}-a$. [MAJOR EDIT: $K$ contains a primitive $p$th root of unity and if $p=2$, also a primitive fourth root of unity.]

Suppose for sake of contradiction that $a\in K$ is not a $p$th power. Then in the tower above, we have degrees $[K(a^{1/p}):K]=p$ and $[K(a^{1/p^2}):K(a^{1/p})]=1$. Then $[K(a^{1/p^2}):K]=p$, and the minimal polynomial of $a^{1/p^2}$ over $K$ (call it $m(x)$) has degree $p$.

From this point I'm stuck. I know $x^{p^2}-a$ is a polynomial over $K$ that has $a^{1/p^2}$ as a root and thus $m(x)$ must divide this polynomial. Additionally, we have the polynomial $x^p-a^{1/p}$, which is a degree $p$ polynomial with $a^{1/p^2}$ as a root, yet it is over $K(a^{1/p})$ and not $K$. It seems like the answer is staring me in the face, but I haven't found it. If you have any hints to get me there, I would very much appreciate them!

Comment: “the contradiction I'm aiming for”: are you trying to show that the properties you list for $K$ and $a$ are inconsistent?

Comment: I think I always forget something when typing out questions! My apologies--I am trying to show that $a\in K$ must always be a $p$th power.

Comment: I don't think what you try to prove is true without some additional assumption. For example, let $K=\Bbb{R}$, $a=-1$, $p=2$. In that case $K(\sqrt{-1})=\Bbb{C}=K((-1)^{1/4})$, but $K(\sqrt{-1})$ is a proper extension of $K$.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct (which I guess makes me feel a bit better than what I was trying to show wasn't true!). It seems as though I made an statement earlier in the problem that was oversimplified things, so I will work backwards and try to reformulate a successful proof. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: I just noticed that the assumption I'm missing is that $K$ contains a primitive $p$th root of unity, and in the case $p=2$, also the primitive fourth root of unity. (Greatly sorry about that--I can't believe I left that out)